# Rails - How to stop idling Spring process automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I found many Spring processes were consuming my pc memory by checking Activity Monitor. They came from my several Rails apps. After executing `spring stop`, they were gone. But I have some on-going Rails projects all the time, so it is difficult to manually type `spring stop` every time.

I want to stop idling Spring process automatically, like Pow. Is there any good idea?